# "Push" linq vs reactive framework

Tags: .net, system.reactive

*(Once again exposing the depths of my ignorance here by combining two concepts which I haven't grokked)*

I read [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2009/11/03/introduction-to-the-reactive-framework-part-ii.aspx) about the [Reactive framework](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Kim-Hamilton-and-Wes-Dyer-Inside-NET-Rx-and-IObservableIObserver-in-the-BCL-VS-2010/) being a 'Push' model compared to Linq's 'Pull' model. This reminded me of reading an article about ['Push' Linq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx).

Is there really any similarity between these two 'frameworks'?

**UPDATE**

Since I asked this question, Jon Skeet has asked it too, here are his [first](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/16/first-encounters-with-reactive-extensions.aspx) and [second](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/19/linq-to-rx-second-impressions.aspx) impressions.

Comment: Comments here seem to indicate that I'm not the first to have asked this question. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/20/efficient-quot-vote-counting-quot-with-linq-to-objects-and-the-value-of-nothing.aspx

Comment: From what I've seen, it seems that Rx is Jon's Push LINQ on steroids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They both give a method of how use linq operators on streaming data.

The Reactive Framework is likely to have wider adoptions.

- I has a nice logical clarity to it.
  The opposite of IEnumerable (pull) can be expressed as it's **dual** in IObservable (push)
- It'll be baked into .Net 4